# Rationale for numpy.split returning a list and not an array

Tags: python, numpy, design-decisions

I was surprised that `numpy.split` yields a `list` and not an `array`. I would have thought it would be better to return an `array`, since `numpy` has put a lot of work into making arrays more useful than lists. Can anyone justify `numpy` returning a `list` instead of an `array`? Why would that be a better programming decision for the numpy developers to have made?

Comment: I'd imagine because `np.split` can can return a jagged list, which wouldn't be handled well by a numpy array.

Comment: Could go in Software Engineering

Comment: Look at the output for `np.split(np.arange(10), [2, 4]))`. Try putting that result in a (jagged) array of object dtype - not so useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comment pointed out that if the slit is uneven, the result can't be a array, at least not one that has the same `dtype`.  At best it would be an `object` dtype.

But lets consider the case of equal length subarrays:

```
In [124]: x = np.arange(10)
In [125]: np.split(x,2)
Out[125]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
In [126]: np.array(_)     # make an array from that
Out[126]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

But we can get the same array without split - just reshape:

```
In [127]: x.reshape(2,-1)
Out[127]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Now look at the code for `split`.  It just passes the task to `array_split`.  Ignoring the details about alternative axes, it just does

```
sub_arys = []
for i in range(Nsections):
    # st and end from `div_points
    sub_arys.append(sary[st:end])
return sub_arys
```

In other words, it just steps through array and returns successive slices.  Those (often) are views of the original.

So `split` is not that sophisticate a function.  You could generate such a list of subarrays yourself without a lot of numpy expertise.

Another point.  Documentation notes that `split` can be reversed with an appropriate `stack`.  `concatenate` (and family) takes a list of arrays.  If give an array of arrays, or a higher dim array, it effectively iterates on the first dimension, e.g. `concatenate(arr) => concatenate(list(arr))`.

Answer (score -2):

Actually you are right it returns a list

```
import numpy as np 
a=np.random.randint(1,30,(2,2))
b=np.hsplit(a,2)
type(b)
```

it will return `type(b)` as list so, there is nothing wrong in the documentation, i also first thought that the documentation is wrong it doesn't return a array, but when i checked

```
type(b[0])
type(b[1])
```

it returned type as ndarray.

it means it returns a list of ndarrary's.